# Getting a UIImage or CIImage from ARReferenceImage

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, aranchor

I am using `ARKit` to do some animation over `ARAnchors`. My images are stored in an `AR Resource Group` like below.

[image]

As such they can be accessed like below in order to load them into my session as tracked images. However, **I would also like to do some separate operations on these same images** and therefore need to access them as either `CIImages` or `UIImages`. Right now I have to import these separately into my project because there doesn't seem to be a way to extract the image from an `ARReferenceImage`. Is there a way to do this? It is quite convenient to use the `AR Resource Group` as it displays relevant warnings about potential conflicts as well as less performant markers before compiling. I also assume it would take more time to load up the app if I were to convert say my PNG images into `CIImages` then into `ARReferenceImage` in my `viewDidLoad()` or by some similar means.

```
guard let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "Photos", bundle: Bundle.main) else {
    print("No images available")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating `ARReferenceImage`s in Xcode doesn’t put the original images into your app’s asset catalog, so the original image isn’t available at run time. (Instead, ARKit pre-processes the image into a form that makes recognition more efficient while using less storage.)

If you want to use an image both for ARKit recognition and for visual display (or other processing), you’ll need to include it in your Asset Catalog twice — once as an AR Reference Image, then again as a normal (`UIImage`) asset.

Alternatively, you could add it to your asset catalog as a normal image, then create an `ARReferenceImage` from it at run time — that class has an initializer that takes `CGImage`. (In that case, it might still be useful to use the AR Reference Images area of the asset catalog to preflight your images and make sure they’re good for recognition, even if you’re not delivering them that way.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense